# Reserve Requirements for Banks

Tags: macroeconomics, federal-reserve, reserve-requirement-ratio

Does the reserve requirements for US depository instiutions require a multi branch institution as a whole be compliant, or each individual branch of that institution be compliant? For example imagine Bank Of America only had two branches and one was below the reserve requirement whereas the other was above, but averaged together they are above the reserve requirement. In this scenario is BoA compliant or does the first branch need to borrow currency from another bank?

Comment: There are no reserve requirements in the US since [march 2020](https://www.federalreserve.gov/monetarypolicy/reservereq.htm#:~:text=As%20announced%20on%20March%2015,requirements%20for%20all%20depository%20institutions.) Prior to that, it was for the entire bank as a whole.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

US reserve requirements were abolished in 2020 (see [Fed](https://www.federalreserve.gov/monetarypolicy/reservereq.htm)) so there aren’t any anymore.

In the past they were applied on a institution level. So they would apply to branch separately only if the branch is created as a separate legal entity (depository institution) but not otherwise (eg sometimes bank owns subsidiary bank as a branch), again see [Fed](https://www.federalreserve.gov/monetarypolicy/reservereq.htm).